# Data is storing automatically in database when i refresh the page

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I made register page with php. When I register one user after filling everything the data is properly storing in database but after that if i refresh the register page without filling anything then the recent user data is again storing in database. Why is like that? and also last scripts are not working

below is my php code

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['register'])) {

    $ip = getIp();

    $c_name = $_POST['c_name'];
    $c_email = $_POST['c_email'];
    $c_pass = $_POST['c_pass'];
    $c_image = $_FILES['c_image']['name'];
    $c_image_tmp = $_FILES['c_image']['tmp_name'];
    $c_country = $_POST['c_country'];
    $c_city = $_POST['c_city'];
    $c_contact = $_POST['c_contact'];
    $c_address = $_POST['c_address'];

    move_uploaded_file($c_image_tmp, "customer/customer_images/$c_image");

      $insert_c = "insert into customers (customer_ip,customer_name,customer_email,customer_pass,customer_country,customer_city,customer_contact,customer_address,customer_image) values ('$ip','$c_name','$c_email','$c_pass','$c_country','$c_city','$c_contact','$c_address','$c_image')";
}
 $run_c = mysqli_query($con, $insert_c);

$sel_cart = "select * from cart where ip_add='$ip'";

$run_cart = mysqli_query($con, $sel_cart);
$check_cart = mysqli_num_rows($run_cart);
if ($check_cart==0) {

    $_SESSION['customer_email']=$c_email;
    echo "<script>alert('Accound has been created successfully')</script>";
    echo "<script>window.open('customer/my_accont.php'.'_self')</script>";
}
else {
    $_SESSION['customer_email']=$c_email;
    echo "<script>alert('Accound has been created successfully')</script>";
    echo "<script>window.open('checkout.php'.'_self')</script>";
}   

 ?>
```

Comment: techguru if one of the answers helped you, please select it (and upvote if you wish). It takes time to research, test and write up these answers. Not very cool to ask & run.

Answer (score 0):

when you refresh a page that has posted a form (method="POST"), you will resend the datas.

Answer (score 0):

> if i refresh the register page without filling anything then the
>   recent user data is again storing in database. Why is like that?

When you refresh a page, the browser re-sends the request from the last page load. So if your form's submission is to the same page it's on, you are probably doing the following:

1. Load the page and fill out the form
2. Submit the form. This causes the browser to `POST` the form submissions to the same page in an http request. Your script receives the requests and registers the user
3. Press refresh.  This causes the browser to `POST` the same submission as before, even though the form looks blank. Your script receives the new request with the same parameters and registers the user

The most effective way to prevent double-storing of the same data is to check whether the data exists before you store it.  Before you execute:

```
insert into customers (customer_ip,customer_name,customer_email...
```

First run the query

```
SELECT customer_email FROM customers WHERE customer_email = '$c_email'
```

Make sure that the zero results are returned before you register that email. If the email is already present, just redirect the customer and exit:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($email_check_result)){
    header('Location: myaccount.php');
    exit;
}
```

You should also design your DB table to never allow two customers to have the same email. Make sure that any field that must not be shared between customers has an index of type `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY` in your DB. [See this reference.](https://www.sitepoint.com/use-unique-indexes-mysql-databases/)

> and also last scripts are not working

Please don't address multiple issues in the same question. Ask a different question once you've sorted out this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the email already exists in database. If exist then dont reenter the data.
Change this line

```
$run_c = mysqli_query($con, $insert_c);
```

To

```
$check_email = "select * from customers where customer_email='$c_email'";

$email = mysqli_query($con, $check_email);
$num_email = mysqli_num_rows($email);
if ($num_email==0) {
  $run_c = mysqli_query($con, $insert_c);
}
```

here you checked if the email exists and if yes it wont re enter in database.